# Why won't this Boolean string format work?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5, boolean, string-formatting

I currently have the following `GridView` `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Despatched">
    <ItemTemplate><%# IIf(Eval("Despatched"), "Yes", "No")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This works fine, but I've read I can do the following instead, which I think is a lot neater:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Despatched" DataField="Despatched" DataFormatString="{0:Yes;No}" />
```

However, this still returns True/False values instead of Yes/No

Why isn't this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read this? Got a link?

Comment: Why is there an extra I at the beginning of you if statement

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko - its the vb.net equivalent to the c# `?:` operator. See [IIf function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Ash: it's VB and that is basically an inline if statement.

Comment: @Ash: It's the IIF function of VB... Something akin to the ? op in C#

Comment: @Ash: That's the VB.Net built-in IIf statement.  LOL!!

Comment: @All - Cheers, I get it now. It's a while since I've done VB :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, bool.ToString() does not support a custom formatting string such as {0:Yes;No} although I truly admit it would be a good idea :-)

The following code:

```
    bool b = true;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:Yes;No}", b);
```

Always display True whatever .NET framework version (2, 3, 4) you use.

Comment: Every one should go and vote for on this at the VisualStudio UserVoice page: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2242024-add-a-iformattable-to-the-boolean-type

Answer (score 1):

You should add `HtmlEncode="false"` to your BoundField with DateFormatString:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Despatched" DataField="Despatched" DataFormatString="{0:Yes;No}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2005/10/31/boundfield-dataformatstring-attribute-not-being-applied.aspx

Comment: Same for me... I read somewhere that there might be a language issues as it seems to be not working using VB.net.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have is accurate.  You might try cleaning and recompiling the site to see if the behavior changes.  If this is from a deployment, delete the destination before copying the new files out.

I just get the feeling that visual studio didn't update your .aspx file on a deployment. Which I've found tends to happen a little too frequently.

Comment: How did you get it to work?  I see "True" and "False" no matter what data format string I use... can you show your code sample?